# Figuring out how to Format Printing

Tags: java, arraylist, printf

I'm having trouble figuring out how to format my printing from arraylist,
I just don't know how to do it. Any tips or snippets that could help? Thank you

```
protected void printTable(ArrayList<double[]> table)
{
    String s = "";
    System.out.printf("\n_____________________________________________________\n");
    System.out.printf("\n  x\t   f[]\t    f[,]    f[,,]    f[,,,]   ");
    System.out.printf("\n_____________________________________________________\n");
    for(int a = 0; a < table.size(); a++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%.3s", s);
        for(double c : table.get(a))
        {
            System.out.printf("%.3f\t " , c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

its printing like this at the moment:

```
    _____________________________________________________
    x      f[]      f[,]    f[,,]    f[,,,]   
    _____________________________________________________
    1.000    1.500   0.000   2.000   
    3.000    3.250   3.000   1.670   
    0.500    0.167   -0.665  
    0.333    -1.663  
    -1.997
```

how do I get it to do?

```
_____________________________________________________

x      f[]      f[,]    f[,,]    f[,,,]   
_____________________________________________________
1.000    3.000   0.500   0.333   -1.997
1.500    3.250   0.167   -1.663  
0.000    3.000   -0.665  
2.000    1.670
```

Answer (score 2):

You can justify your columns using - flag

```
System.out.printf("%-.3f\t " , c);
```

And you can specify the width using (change the 10 width to whatever you want)

```
System.out.printf("%-10.3f " , c);
```

I would suggest that you remove the `\t` and rather control the width using the width and precision flags (`10.3` in above example)

You can control the order of the printing using a 2 dimensional array instead of an ArrayList of array

```
double table [][];
```

Comment: Instead of an ArrayList of arrays, you could use a 2 dimensional array, double[][]. Then you can control your iterators more explicitly

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void printTable(ArrayList<double[]> table)
{
    String s = "";
    System.out.printf("\n_____________________________________________________\n");
    System.out.printf("\n  x\t   f[]\t    f[,]    f[,,]    f[,,,]   ");
    System.out.printf("\n_____________________________________________________\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        for(int a = 0; a < table.size(); a++)
        {
            if ( table.get(a).length > i ) {
                System.out.printf("%.3f\t " , table.get(a)[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below rotates matrix for your scenario, but I have only checked for a nXn matrix, you should be able to work your way out of it.

```
    public void printTable(ArrayList<double[]> table)
{
    String s = "";
    System.out.printf("\n_____________________________________________________\n");
    System.out.printf("\n  x\t   f[]\t    f[,]    f[,,]    f[,,,]   ");
    System.out.printf("\n_____________________________________________________\n");
    int i =0;

    for(int a = 0; a < table.size(); a++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%.3s", s);
        for(int j= 0;j<table.size();j++){
            double[] d = table.get(j);

            for(int k =a;k<=a;k++){
                System.out.printf("%.3f\t " , d[k]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```